# File path normalizer

Tags: c++, strings

I recently wrote a file path normalizing function, with normalizing a pure lexical process. This means the function is unaware of the filesystem, and would not for instance consider symbolic links or know the current directory.

Normalizing is defined as

- Remove any `.` directory
- Replace consecutive delimiters with a single one
- Replace delimiters with the one passed in
- Remove ordered pairs of names and `..` separated by a delimiter recursively

---

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<stdexcept>

std::string normalize(const std::string& path, char delimiter = '/')
{
    static constexpr char delims[] = "/\\";
    static const auto error = std::logic_error("bad path");

    std::string norm;
    norm.reserve(path.size() / 2);  // random guess, should be benchmarked

    for(auto it = path.begin(); it != path.end(); it++)
    {
        if(std::any_of(std::begin(delims),
                        std::end(delims),
                        [it](auto c){ return c == *it; }))
        {
            if(norm.empty() || norm.back() != delimiter)
                norm.push_back(delimiter);
        }
        else if(*it == '.')
        {
            if(++it == path.end())
                break;
            if(std::any_of(std::begin(delims),
                        std::end(delims),
                        [it](auto c){ return c == *it; }))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if(*it != '.')
                throw error;
            if(norm.empty() || norm.back() != delimiter)
                throw error;

            norm.pop_back();
            while(!norm.empty())
            {
                norm.pop_back();
                if(norm.back() == delimiter)
                {
                    norm.pop_back();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            norm.push_back(*it);
    }
    if(!norm.empty() && norm.back() != delimiter)
        norm.push_back(delimiter);
    return norm;
}
```

In particular, there are a few things that stood out

- Seeing as the path may be relative and the function knows nothing about the current directory, the function cannot normalize (as defined) `../something`, the function currently considers it an error.
- The use of `std::any_of` makes it trivial to replace `delims`, but the if statement becomes less readable.
- Repetitively checking edge cases (eg `norm.empty()`), which is a common theme in string manipulation, feels plain wrong.

Comment: You should define _normalization_. As written, the code throws on `.` and `..` paths, which I'd consider _normal_.

Comment: Have you looked at `boost::filesystem`? Do you have access to the Filesystem TS (`std::experimental::filesystem`)?

Comment: @Snowhawk04 They apparently does what this does, thanks. I'd really love to get some input about the string manipulation part still though, every time I write this kind of stuff, it hurts.

Comment: @vnp After stewing on it a bit, `.` seems perfectly normal as you said. Defined normalize. Changed the code a bit, should I be changing the code after asking?